# Get Mondays of every second month

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to get the date of every monday skipping a month each time but I keep getting only the monday of the first week. This is my code:

```
$begin = new \DateTime("2017-04-01");
$end = new \DateTime("2017-08-31");

$interval = \DateInterval::createFromDateString("next monday of +2 months");
$period = new \DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
foreach ( $period as $dt )
            {
// echo the date for each monday found in the second month
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you got wrong end date

Comment: Sorry about that, it was a typo in the codes posted here. It should be 2017-08-31 as the end date. I am updating now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have mixed the `$begin` and `$end` values. Also, the `DateInterval` will only have one Monday every single month. I was not able to find a interval expression to get every Monday in every other month, so I did the filtering manually. In this example we use the month from the begin date, and includes the Mondays from that date, skip two months and so on.

```
<?php
$end = new \DateTime("2017-04-01");
$begin = new \DateTime("2007-08-31");
$month_even = ((int) $begin->format('m')) % 2 === 0;

$interval = \DateInterval::createFromDateString("next monday");
$period = new \DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
foreach ($period as $dt) {
    // Check if we want to show even months, make sure that the current month is even
    // or, if we want to show odd months, the month should be odd.
    if ((((int) $dt->format('m')) % 2 === 0) === $month_even) {
        echo $dt->format('d-m-Y') . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
31-08-2007
01-10-2007
[...]
06-02-2017
13-02-2017
20-02-2017
27-02-2017
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I fixed a typo for the end date, getting only the first week still.

Comment: @johntully First week? Do you only get one single results? I got 57 results. They are all the first Monday in every second month, which is what I thought you wanted?

Comment: I am looking for all Modays in every second month so there should be 4 per month but I get only the first monday.

Comment: Ah, well, then the problem is the `DateInterval` you define. Let me give it a go.

Comment: Btw, if you want the ordering to be different, please specify how you "decide" which month to start listing Mondays from. Right now that is kind of hard to guess.

Comment: Brilliant!, This works great. Thanks. Is it possible to start from the current month then skip the next and so on?

Comment: @johntully I changed the code to use the month from the ´$begin` variable, if that was what you meant?